# D3 point scale with control over ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have to draw a chart like this:
[image]

I have tried with `d3.scalePoint()` after failing with `d3.scaleBand()`. ScalePoint is a huge plus for me however, the ticks are spread across the axes with their own algorithm. I have to keep the ticks controlled based on items they have inside them, top of each set of items..

The following is example data:

```
[{label: "Rem1 #EVT", value: 55}
{label: "Rem1 #P1", value: 28}
{label: "Rem1 #P2", value: 40}
{label: "Rem1 #CRB", value: 75}
{label: "Rem1 #OVB", value: 50}
{label: "Rem2 #EVT", value: 77}
{label: "Rem2 #P1", value: 18}
{label: "Rem2 #P2", value: 85}
{label: "Rem2 #CRB", value: 7}
{label: "Rem2 #OVB", value: 59}
{label: "Rem3 #EVT", value: 57}
{label: "Rem3 #P1", value: 82}
{label: "Rem3 #P2", value: 45}
{label: "Rem3 #CRB", value: 50}
{label: "Rem3 #OVB", value: 24}
{label: "Rem4 #EVT", value: 34}
{label: "Rem4 #P1", value: 72}
{label: "Rem4 #P2", value: 57}
{label: "Rem4 #CRB", value: 98}
{label: "Rem4 #OVB", value: 36}
{label: "Rem5 #EVT", value: 30}
{label: "Rem5 #P1", value: 51}
{label: "Rem5 #P2", value: 94}
{label: "Rem5 #CRB", value: 57}
{label: "Rem5 #OVB", value: 83}
{label: "Rem6 #EVT", value: 68}
{label: "Rem6 #P1", value: 88}
{label: "Rem6 #P2", value: 41}
{label: "Rem6 #CRB", value: 81}
{label: "Rem6 #OVB", value: 25}
{label: "Rem7 #EVT", value: 47}
{label: "Rem7 #P1", value: 72}
{label: "Rem7 #P2", value: 36}
{label: "Rem7 #CRB", value: 25}
{label: "Rem7 #OVB", value: 81}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some data?

Comment: Update the question with sample data @MichaelRovinsky

Comment: Well, according to your drawing and description, you don't need a scale at all. You can simply render your chart with enter/exit pattern and set the width of each bar by the value: width = maxWidth * value / maxValue.

Comment: though the bars I drew seems equal, they should be scaled. Also for labels of y Axis, I need scale. I didn't mention to avoid complexity, I have a n*n grid for background and their labels on bottom Axis

Comment: I think you don't need y-scale either. Just create a <g> element for each row and set its `transform=translate(0, index * rowHeight)`, then put bars and labels under <g>

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky, yes for my thing I managed without Y-Axis at all. Thanks for the out-of-the-box suggestion. However Y-Axis would help in label alignments and text-anchor. (If anyone reads this)

Comment: So I suppose you have it done, or still need some assistance with D3?